# JS Mobile Navigation isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mobile

I am trying to code my new site and am having issues with the JS file not responding to the navigation file.

The Head and Navigation files are both .php files in my site. the testing site can be found here: http://testsite.laurenkapraun.com/

I am still working on making the rest of the site responsive, but am focusing on the navigation first.

Please let me know if I have left anything out that would be helpful. Thanks!!

I have included code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mobile .header .menu-toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next(".mobile .primaryMenu").toggle(0, "display");
  });
});
```

```css
/*Navigation*/

@media screen and (max-width: 738px) {
  .line {
    display: block !important;
    width: 30px;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  .menu-toggle:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .primaryMenu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  .mobile {
    display: block !important;
    background: #f7f6f1 !important;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  .mobile .primaryMenu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .mobile .primaryMenu li a {
    color: #989AA4;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
  }
  .mobile .primaryMenu li a:hover {
    background-color: #8a43a3;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .primaryMenu li {
    display: block;
  }
  .primaryMenu .wrap {
    padding: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--Head-->
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title><?php if ($thisPage!="") echo " $thisPage"; ?> | Lauren Kapraun Portfolio</title>
 <meta name="title" content="<?php if ($thisPage!="") echo " $thisPage"; ?>" | Lauren Kapraun Portfolio />
 
 <!--CSS-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/main.css" type="text/css" media="all">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/mobile.css" type="text/css" media="all">
 
 <!--JS-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/nav.js"></script>
 
 
 <!--External-->
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>


<!--Navigation-->
<div class="mobile">
 <div class="header">
  <div class="menu-toggle">
   <div class="line"></div>
   <div class="line"></div>
   <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <nav id="menu-top" role="navigation" aria-label="Top Menu" style="transition: max-height 350ms ease 0s; position: relative;" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="primaryMenu">
   <div class="wrap">
    <ul id="menu-top-items">
     <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Home") echo " class=\"currentPage\""; ?>><a href="../index.php">Home</a></li>
     <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Technical") echo " class=\"currentPage\""; ?>><a href="../technical.php">Technical</a></li>
     <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Visual") echo " class=\"currentPage\""; ?>><a href="../visual.php">Visual</a></li>
     <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Video") echo " class=\"currentPage\""; ?>><a href="../video.php">Video</a></li>
     <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Sound") echo " class=\"currentPage\""; ?>><a href="../sound.php">Sound</a></li>
     <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Contact") echo " class=\"currentPage\""; ?>><a href="../contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you maintain js in that root folder with your php page ?

Comment: First check jQuery file and include it on the bottom of the page for faster running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to your site I noticed in the console it says
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
I also notice you have several links to different jQuery, using one will suffice. 
I also noticed the link to jquery-1.4.2.js seems weird, check that? The jQuery code itself for the menu looks fine.

this line here

```
$(this).parent().next(".mobile .primaryMenu").toggle(0, "display");
```

.primaryMenu is actualy wrapped in a nav and this could be simplified as

```
$(".primaryMenu").toggle(0, "display");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mobile .header .menu-toggle").click(function() {
    $(".primaryMenu").toggle(0, "display");
  });
});
```

```css
 .line {
    display: block !important;
    width: 30px;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  .menu-toggle:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .primaryMenu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  .mobile {
    display: block !important;
    background: #f7f6f1 !important;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  .mobile .primaryMenu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .mobile .primaryMenu li a {
    color: #989AA4;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
  }
  .mobile .primaryMenu li a:hover {
    background-color: #8a43a3;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .primaryMenu li {
    display: block;
  }
  .primaryMenu .wrap {
    padding: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile">
 <div class="header">
  <div class="menu-toggle">
   <div class="line"></div>
   <div class="line"></div>
   <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <nav id="menu-top" role="navigation" aria-label="Top Menu" style="transition: max-height 350ms ease 0s; position: relative;" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="primaryMenu">
   <div class="wrap">
    <ul id="menu-top-items">
     <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Home") echo " class=\"currentPage\""; ?>><a href="../index.php">Home</a></li>
     <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Technical") echo " class=\"currentPage\""; ?>><a href="../technical.php">Technical</a></li>
     <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Visual") echo " class=\"currentPage\""; ?>><a href="../visual.php">Visual</a></li>
     <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Video") echo " class=\"currentPage\""; ?>><a href="../video.php">Video</a></li>
     <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Sound") echo " class=\"currentPage\""; ?>><a href="../sound.php">Sound</a></li>
     <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Contact") echo " class=\"currentPage\""; ?>><a href="../contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated the code above. The error in the console is gone, but I am still having issues with the menu not opening.

Comment: I just updated my answer the primary menu is actually wrapped in a nav container. See above.

Comment: I am so sorry to bother you again, somewhere in the process of pushing my site to the public_html folder, the mobile menu stopped working again. Would you mind taking a look at it? I am not sure what would have changed since making the updates: https://www.laurenkapraun.com/

Comment: Your site is using https, but jQuery is being loaded http, try using https like so instead: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js